https://m365x77052727.sharepoint.com/sites/USSales/DOC1/DOc1/DOC2/DOC3/Doc4/DOC5 unable to rename the folder DOC5 using graph explorer
1 Getting error sometimes its unable to found item sometimes bad request. While I'm trying to access this particular DOC5 folder and rename it I'm getting error
1 Getting error sometimes its unable to found item sometimes bad request. While I'm trying to access this particular DOC5 folder and rename it I'm getting error

You can edit any elements in SharePoint Designer if you have access.
